# uidrange iproute2 not working

Tags: linux, routing, ipv4

I'm trying to setup routing based on uidrange, and I seem to keep hitting the same issue.

```
$ whoami
yawnt
$ id
uid=1000(yawnt)
$ ip rule list
0: from all lookup local
32765: from all uidrange 1000-1000 lookup custom
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
$ ip route list table custom
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

With this configuration, there is no internet connection. Traceroute just hangs. On a TCP level, I see SYN being sent, SYN/ACK being received, but then no ACK being sent from my computer.

However, if I change the rule 32765 to "from all lookup custom", then it works.

```
$ sudo ip rule del uidrange 1000-1000
$ sudo ip rule add lookup custom
$ ip rule list
0: from all lookup local
32765: from all lookup custom
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
$ curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
...
```

I'm running ArchLinux with iproute2 version 5.5.0. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Following up from your comment, I had already tried flushing my iptables and is completely empty. You mentioned it works in your setup. Is that while trying to reach an internet host through your router with a custom table as I have? Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you again for the reply. configuration can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/yawnt/56183cb2f7bb70986056cda15c7d84fd). I'm starting to think it's not related to the internet at all (see note in the gist). this is so puzzling.

Comment: apologies, forgot the ip route, will add to the gist

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I'm facing the exact same issue right now and have already spent a lot of time troubleshooting this issue...

Comment: I did get it to work, but I couldn't pinpoint one specific step that fixed it for me so I can't be of much help. I can tell you that during my investigation I found dropwatch extremely useful because it told me that incoming packets were dropped by the kernel and where it happened. You need kernel debug symbols installed for that.

Comment: The way I ended up troubleshooting it was first with UDP servers (with netcat) and then TCP (also netcat) using dropwatch

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problems as well. My problem was a missing default route in the main routing table. I figured it wouldn't need to be there if the main table wasn't used but I was wrong :)
Good recommendation on dropwatch. I'll keep that in mind for the next time I need to solve routing problems :)

Comment: For the part where you mention "Traceroute just hangs", you might want to check if there is a setuid for root on the binary file.  Traceroute is often installed as setuid.  This would make your uidrange at 1000, not match for when you run the traceroute program.  Ping can sometimes still be seen with a setuid flag also.  Although these days it's often installed using the "capabilities" feature instead of setuid.